# How to update href link using jquery having WooCommerce functions

Tags: jquery, html

how can I update my link having Woocommerce functions using jquery? I am using jquery to get the quantity of product on change. See the code

```
echo '<div class="whtsapp_order"><a id="the-link" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' . '+92383726277' . '&text=' .'I want to order' . '%20' . get_the_title() . '%20' . get_the_permalink() .'%20' .'quanity:1'. '">';

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.qty').change(function(){
        var var_id = $('.qty').val();
        $("a#the-link").attr("href", "");
    });    
 });
</script>
```

I want to update the href link with new quantity value.

Comment: Is `.whtsapp_order` update dynamically? Where this code is placed? What hook you are using here? Please provide enough details

Comment: @Ramesh I placed this code on the woocommerce product page next to add to cart button

Comment: It's not a good practice to add such additional code directly to the `woocommerce template`. They've provide enough `hooks` to do these things. Learn about woocommerce hooks here : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/  Also follow the visual guide : https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Comment: @Ramesh my question was about asking how to update the href link having a woocommerce functios. But you are telling me to read about the hooks

Comment: I had the same issue once, and I couldn't find any solution for it. After that I got to know about this hooks things and I used it and it worked perfectly. The only change I made is used the hook, didn't change any of the code.

Comment: ok thanks. I am checking the links now that you provided me